# A question related to the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture on odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Good day to everyone!  I apologize in advance for the somewhat long post, but I had to put in all the details into a single question to communicate what I believe to be a viable approach to odd perfect numbers.

A positive integer $N$ is said to *perfect* if $\sigma(N) = 2N$, where $\sigma$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example, $6$ is perfect since the divisors of $6$ are $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$, and thus $\sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 12 = 2 \cdot 6$.  So far, all of the known examples for perfect numbers are even, and it is currently an open problem to either find an *odd perfect number* or show that none exists.  The general consensus among mathematicians is that odd perfect numbers do not exist.

Euler gave the general form that an odd perfect number $N$ must take.  This is $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ where $q$ is prime with $\gcd(q, n) = 1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Descartes (and Frenicle) believed that $k = 1$ (see Beasley's overview paper detailing this [here](http://www.acmsonline.org/conferences/2013/ACMS-2013-Proceedings.pdf)) - more recently, Sorli conjectured the same in his [Ph.D. thesis](http://epress.lib.uts.edu.au/research/handle/2100/275).

Lastly, Descartes "saw no reason why an odd perfect number could not exist", and gave an example of a number $D$ that comes *very close to perfection* (which, in modern terminology, is called a [Descartes number](http://www.math.missouri.edu/~bbanks/papers/2008_Descartes_Final.pdf), of which only one is currently known):

$$D = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{11^2}\cdot{13^2}\cdot{22021} = 198585576189$$

If $22021$ were prime, then $D$ would have been an odd perfect number.  Alas, $22021 = {19^2}\cdot{61}$ is composite, and the number $D$ is not perfect.

In a [paper published in JIS](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), Dris showed that the inequality $n < q$ would imply that $k = 1$ (which we can call the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli [or simply D-F-S] conjecture on odd perfect numbers).

In the following, assume that the D-F-S conjecture is true.  Then we have $k = 1$, and the odd perfect number $\bar{N}$ takes the form $\bar{N} = qn^2$.

Since the abundancy index $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ is weakly multiplicative (a property which it inherits from the sum-of-divisors $\sigma(x)$), then we have:

$$I(\bar{N}) = \sigma(\bar{N})/\bar{N} = 2 = I(q)\cdot{I(n^2)}$$

because $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

Since $\sigma(q) = q + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $n$ is odd, then $\sigma(q) \neq n$.

Therefore, either $\sigma(q) < n$ or $n < \sigma(q)$.

> > *CLAIM 1*: $q < n \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(q) < n$

The claim follows by observing that $q < n < \sigma(q) = q + 1$ is impossible when $q$ and $n$ are positive integers.

> > *CLAIM 2*: $\sqrt{2} < I(n)$

In fact, $$I(n) > \left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)} > 1.4444.$$
[This was communicated via e-mail by Ochem to Dris in April of 2013.  See pages $3$ to $5$ of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6001v1.pdf) in the arXiv for more details.]

It follows from *CLAIM 2* that $I(qn) = I(q)\cdot{I(n)} > \sqrt{2}$.

We therefore have:

$$\sqrt{2} < \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} = I(q)\cdot{I(n)} < 2$$

since $qn$ is *deficient*, being a *proper divisor* of the odd perfect number $\bar{N} = qn^2$.

In particular, if $q < n$, we have $\sigma(q)/n < 1$, so that:

$$\sqrt{2} < \frac{\sigma(q)}{n}\frac{\sigma(n)}{q} < \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}.$$

Thus,

$$q < n \Longrightarrow \sigma(q)/n < 1 < \sigma(q)/q \leq 6/5 < \sqrt{2} < \sigma(n)/n < \sigma(n)/q.$$

Of course, we already know that $I(n) = \sigma(n)/n < 2$ since $n$ is deficient, being a proper divisor of the odd perfect number $\bar{N} = qn^2$.  Alas, I currently do not know if $\sigma(n)/q$ can be bounded from above.

By assuming the D-F-S conjecture, an obvious upper bound would be

$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} > \frac{\sigma(n)}{q}.$$

But then again, I know of no upper bound for $\sigma(n^2)/q$.  If there was such an upper bound, then by the results of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1437v5.pdf) in the arXiv, there would only be finitely many odd perfect numbers.

My question now is this:  If my penultimate goal were to prove the biconditional

$$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow n < q$$

(so that the D-F-S conjecture would then imply that the *Euler prime* $q$ is the largest prime factor of $\bar{N} = qn^2$), I was wondering if anyone out there have any *bright* ideas on how a contradiction might be derived from everything that I've written so far.

Any helpful insights will be appreciated!

> > Postscript: Logically, since the implication $n < q \Longrightarrow k = 1$ is true, and
> >
> > since either the biconditional
> >
> > $$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow n < q$$
> >
> > is true or false (but not both), then either the implication
> >
> > $$k = 1 \Longrightarrow n < q$$ is true or false (but not both).
> >
> > If it is false, then $k = 1$ and $q < n$, from which it follows that $q^k < n$.
> >
> > On the other hand, if $n < q^k$ is true, then the biconditional
> >
> > $$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow n < q$$
> >
> > is true.